# CakePHP sends multiple emails instead of one

Tags: mysql, email, cakephp-2.0

I have a weird bug. I have a script that sends daily emails for ~12K users. It was working nicely for about 3  month then couple of day ago it started to spam. It sent about 15 copies of the email to all the users and they, of course, started complain. The script gets activated by cron job once a day and, according to the server's support, it was fired only once without any problem. When I try to fire script to only one email address it works fine but when I tried to fire all emails again I got the same problem of getting multiple copies. I fired it to the same email address just to avoid spamming users again. I put some log statements to see count and emails that gets fired and  saw something weird: once it gets toward the end of the users's list I saw emails from the start of the list got fired. Something like:

```
    2014-04-13 04:33:02 Email: 12340 yyy@gmail.com
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 12341 yyy@hotmail.com
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: Daily email function got called <- looks like it gets trough new iterations
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 12342 yyy@gmail.com
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 12343 yyy@o2.pl
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 12344 yyy@yahoo.com
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 12345 yyy@aol.com
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 12346 yyy@outlook.com
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 12347 yyy@hotmail.com
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 1 yyy@gmail.com       
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 12348 yyy@comcast.net
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 2 yyy@yahoo.com
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 12349 yyy@yahoo.es
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 3 yyy@hotmail.com
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 12350 yyy@hotmail.com
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 4 yyy@yahoo.com
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 12351 yyy@gmail.com
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 5 yyy@gmail.com.com
2014-04-13 04:33:03 Email: 12352 yyy@hotmail.com
```

It looks like the script got called second time but what might call it?

The function:

```
 function daily_email() {
        CakeLog::write('email', 'Daily email function got called');
        $count = 0;
        ini_set("memory_limit", "2048M");
        set_time_limit("0");
        $from = array('yyy@yyyy.com' => 'yyyyyyyyy');
        $subject = 'bla';
        $template = 'daily';
        $layout = 'daily_layout';
        $users_data = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.unsubscribed ' => '0')));
        foreach ($users_data as $user) {
            $count++;
            $user = $user['User'];
            $to = $user['email_address'];
            $s5 = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 31); //change security string every day
            $offer_link = 'http://bla.bla.com' . $s5;
            $unsubscribe_link = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/dailies/user/unsubscribe/" . $user['id'];
            $this->Emailer->send_email($from, $to, $subject, $template, $layout, $offer_link, $unsubscribe_link, $s5);
            $this->User->id = $user['id'];
            $user['is_used'] = 0;
            $user['security_string'] = $s5;
            $this->User->save($user);
        }
        CakeLog::write('email', 'Sent ' . $count . ' emails');
        $this->autoRender = false;
    }
```

The email component:

```
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class EmailerComponent extends Component {

    function send_email($from, $to, $subject, $template, $layout, $offer_link, $unsubscribe_link, $s5=null) {
        $email = new CakeEmail();
        $email->template($template, $layout);
        $email->emailFormat('html');         
        $email->to($to);
        $email->from($from);
        $email->subject($subject);
        $email  ->viewVars(array('offer_link' => $offer_link, 'unsubscribe_link' => $unsubscribe_link, 's5' => $s5));
       $email ->send();
    }
}
```

Cron job:

```
0 4 * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://www.myNiceSite.com/dailies/user/daily_email
```

Also, not sure if it's related but ps aux shows two processes once the script runs.

Thank you guys in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the source of the problem. Wget calls the script and waits for response but it takes too long to the script to complete. So wget calls again and it enters, possible, in infinite loop. Right now the fix is to set a flag in database when script runs, it prevents the script from running second time.